# Template argument deduction doesn't work the same as in structured binding

Tags: c++, generics, stl

I formally been told(some books or in web) that the type deduction in `auto` is the same as argument type deduction in `template`.

However, codes below doesn't compile successfully because it's raises `increment of read-only reference a` error. Though the template version deduct `T` as type `int` instead of `const int &`. Why these two cases have different deduction results?

```cpp
#include "bits/stdc++.h"

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T minmax2(T n1, T n2) {
    n1++;
    return n2;
}

int main() {
    auto [a, b] = minmax(1, 2); // minmax() return const T &
    a++;                        // compile error: can not alter read-only varaible.
    const int & c = 1, & d = 2;
    minmax2(c, d);              // the same parameter type, don't raise error
}
```

Another example:

```cpp
int tmp = 1;
const int & test() {
    return tmp;
}

template <typename T>
void test1(T n) {
    n++;  // no error
}
int main() {
    auto a = test(); // If the satement is true, I expect this is the same as test1.
    a++; // no compile error, which is different with the previous code exp
    const int & b = 2;
    test1(b);
}
```

Comment: Your `minmax2` has a very different signature than `std::minmax`. Why do you expect the same result for both?

Comment: Your question is unrelated to template type deduction and `auto`.

Comment: I expect it bind like this: `auto [T a, T b]` like template argument deduction.

Comment: @cigien Would you please explain how does the compile deduct types of a and b.

Comment: Are you aware that a type doesn't contain cv qualifiers and references? The type `T` in `test1` is deduced as `int`. You are calling the function and passing the argument by  value. But this is still completely unrelated to template type deduction and `auto`. The function signatures are just different.

Comment: @ThomasSablik My mistake, but still can't figure out why they are the same while with differenr result

Comment: Because the function signatures are completely different. Why would you expect the same results with different function signatures? You can make it `void test1(const T &n)` to get similar compiler errors.

Comment: I thought they works the same means that `auto a` equals to `T a in tempalte fn`. If they are different, what's the signature of `auto a =  b`?

Comment: You should probably read Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers. It's described there. That's not the right platform to discuss such topics. You are asking multiple questions and changing your question.

Comment: No, I have not changed my  question, all appended contents are all related to my confusion which I posted initially.

Comment: Actually you are asking how type deduction works. That is at least one chapter in a book. That's to broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BAKEZQ There is no error with your second example, at least in my case: https://godbolt.org/z/sPvrhP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the fact that *structured bindings* behave a bit differently than the ordinary `auto`, at least from the user's perspective. Consider the latter first:

```
const int& i = 0;
auto j = i;
std::cout << &i << std::endl;
std::cout << &j << std::endl; // different address
j++; // compiles
```

Here, `i` and `j` refer to different objects and the type of `j` is `int` (not `const int` or `const int&`). This exactly corresponds with the template argument deduction when the argument is passed by value.

But with structured bindings, the situation is different:

```
int c = 0, d = 0;
auto [a, b] = std::pair<const int&, const int&>(c, d);
std::cout << &a << std::endl;
std::cout << &c << std::endl; // same address
// a++; // would not compile
```

Here, the type of `a` and `b` is `const int&` and both `a` and `c` refer to the same object.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Wq1zsz

---

Actually, structured bindings also ignores *const* and *reference* parts of an initialization expression, but at an "outer" level, that is, at a level of `std::pair` in our case:

```
const auto& p = std::make_pair(c, d);
auto [x, y] = p;
std::cout << &p.first << std::endl;
std::cout << &x << std::endl; // different address
```

Here, `x` is a new object with type `int`. If we used `const auto& [x, y] = p;` instead, then `x` would refer to `p.first` and its type would be `const int&`.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me. I have edited my answer, the second case indeed doesn't raise error when compiling. Your explanation and code example is clear enough to help my 
 rationalize what happened, now I can stick to what I thought about auto and template deduction again.

Comment: To make sure I totally understand, If this statement is true? `a` has the same type of `const int &` in example 1 is because that the T is deducted as `pair<const int &, const int &>`, and it's member type is `const int &` and another pair object is created from the source(use member initialization).

Answer (score 0):

Your comment already states your problem: `// minmax() return const T &`

[cppreference for std::minmax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax)

After your binding, you essentially have the following variables: `const int &a` and `const int &b`, afterwards you're trying to increment your const reference of `a` which is obviously not working.

To fix your code, you can simply create a copy of `a` like this:

```
auto [a, b] = minmax(1, 2); // minmax() return const T &
auto a_cpy = a;
++a_cpy;
```

Comment: I expect it bind like this: `auto [T a, T b]` like template argument deduction.

Comment: yes my mistake, `a` and `b` are of type `const int` not `const int&`.

Comment: If I pass references  into template function as signature`(Ta, T b)`, it will deduct the type as `int`

Comment: @ThomasSablik I thought that `auto` removes the reference, but it really doesn't seem to be the case with structured bindings: https://godbolt.org/z/8ET76j. My bad.

Comment: @s0LA Sorry, I was wrong, it seems to be really `const int&`. Demo in my previous comment demonstrate this.

Comment: I should also have double checked before wrongly believing something. I actually have thought that the signature with the `std::initializer_list` will be called. Well, checking something yourself is always the better option.

Comment: @s0LA Agree. That's why I so much like Compiler Explorer :).

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `std::minmax` is

```
template< class T >
std::pair<const T&,const T&> minmax( const T& a, const T& b );
```

The call

```
auto [a, b] = minmax(1, 2);
```

has equivalent behavior to

```
std::pair<const int&,const int&> temp = minmax(1, 2);
const int &a = temp.first;
const int &b = temp.second;
```

That is how structured binding works.

As you can see the type `T` is deduced as `int`. `std::minmax` adds a `const` and a `&` to the type and makes a pair of it.

You could write your own `minmax2` as

```
template <typename T>
std::pair<T,T> minmax2(T n1, T n2) {
    return std::make_pair(n1, n2);
}
```

The call

```
auto [a, b] = minmax2(1, 2);
```

has equivalent behavior to

```
std::pair<int, int> temp = minmax2(1, 2);
int &a = temp.first;
int &b = temp.second;
```

Here you can

```
++a;
```

Comment: So it's not the same as template arg deduction?

Comment: @BAKEZQ It is the same. The type `T` is deduced as `int`. But the return type of `std::minmax` is not `T`. It's `std::pair<const T&,const T&>`.

Comment: If I pass references into template function as signature(Ta), it will deduct the type as `int`

Comment: @BAKEZQ The const reference is not related to `auto`, structured binding or template type deduction. It is the return type of `std::minmax`. If the return type of `std::minmax` were `std::pair<T,T>` you could increment it.

Comment: How to explain my previous behavior in my previous comment and what exactly does `it's the same` mean?

Comment: @BAKEZQ That's how type deduction works. `T` is the type without `const` and `&`.

Comment: Then why it doesn't work like auto `[T a, T b]`, T is the type without const and & as you said.

Comment: @BAKEZQ `std::minmax` makes it a const reference. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: I know that, I am just tring to deduct the type like in template argument.Maybe they are not the same, so I deduct wrong type.

Comment: @BAKEZQ Are you talking about perfect forwarding and universal references?

Comment: No,  I update my question and listed another example, just can't fugure out why auto and T are the same.

Comment: I think the OP's confusion comes from the fact that "ordinary" `auto` ignores _const_ and _reference_ of an expression, but structured bindings does not at a level of particular elements: https://godbolt.org/z/Wq1zsz (which I didn't know either).